# What is a "pluggable" API?

Tags: api, terminology

I'm evaluating a piece of software (uPortal), and it lists one of its features as "Pluggable APIs."

I know what an API is, but have not heard the pluggable term before.  What does it mean for an API to be "pluggable"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that you can replace the implementation. Like a provider model, like ODBC database drivers - you can plug in drivers for various databases, using the same API.

Comment: Could we get an example for a pluggable API?